# Invalid initializer in C struct

Tags: c, struct, initialization, declaration

I have a code that does not work when I try to compile it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s{
    char a;
}s1 = 'A';

int main(){
    struct s *ptr = &s1;
    printf("%c", ptr->a);
}
```

However, when I try to run a similar piece of code using an array, it works perfectly fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s{
    char *q;
}s1[]= {"A"};

int main(){
    struct s *ptr = &s1;
    printf("%s", ptr->q);
}
```

Why does it work when I use a pointer inside struct and not a normal char, isn't the arrow operator used to access the members of the struct variable?

I expected the first piece of code to give a similar output to the first, but it gives me an error saying "Invalid Initialization". I just don't understand why it works with an array and pointer but not simple char.

Comment: The second example would have made more sense if you use the same structure, with a plain single `char` member. The more similar the two examples are the better it's for comparison.

Comment: Also note that in the second example, the definition `struct s *ptr = &s1;` is wrong. The type of `&s1` is `struct s (*)[1]`. Use `struct s *ptr = s1;` instead (because then `s1` will decay to `&s1[0]`).

Comment: And please try to clarify your question: Is it why `struct s s1 = 'A';` doesn't work, but `struct s s2[] = { 'A' };` works? Why the first needs a `{}` around the structure initializer, but it's not needed when defining an array? Please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: And please not that the second example with the array would [result in a compiler warning](https://godbolt.org/z/PdKoPYbjE) with the correct build options.

Comment: I understood  the problem, and my question was actually why the code 1 wasn't working, and I didn't notice the wrong pointer initialization in main(), I'm sorry.

Comment: Note that using braces around an initializer is always valid — even with `int i = { 0 };` — though for simple scalar types like `int`, the braces are optional and aconventional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the integer character constant in braces as you did with initialization the object of the second structure

```
struct s{
    char a;
}s1 = { 'A' };
```

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 16 Otherwise, the initializer for an object that has aggregate or
> union type shall be a brace-enclosed list of initializers for the
> elements or named members.

An exclusion exists for using string literals as initializers of character arrays that may be used without braces.

For example these declarations are equivalent

```
char s[] = { "Hello" };
```

and

```
char s[] = "Hello";
```

Nevertheless the second program is also incorrect.

You declared an array of objects of a structure type

```
struct s{
    char *q;
}s1[]= {"A"};
```

The declaration is equivalent to

```
struct s{
    char *q;
}s1[1]= {"A"};
```

Such an initialization is valid due to the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 20 If the aggregate or union contains elements or members that are
> aggregates or unions, these rules apply recursively to the
> subaggregates or contained unions. If the initializer of a
> subaggregate or contained union begins with a left brace, the
> initializers enclosed by that brace and its matching right brace
> initialize the elements or members of the subaggregate or the
> contained union. **Otherwise, only enough initializers from the list
> are taken to account for the elements or members of the subaggregate
> or the first member of the contained union; any remaining initializers
> are left to initialize the next element or member of the aggregate of
> which the current subaggregate or contained union is a part**.

The expression `&s1` has the type `struct s( * )[1]` but it is assigned to a pointer of the type `struct s *`

```
struct s *ptr = &s1;
```

There is no implicit conversion between these pointer types.

The compiler should issue a warning.  You should not ignore compiler warnings.

The code works because the address of an object of a structure type is equal to the address of its first data member.

Comment: I think the question is, why is it possible to initialize a structure inside an array without `{}`, but not when it's defined as a single structure object.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistakes in the question, it was my first time posting over here, and also I'm new to C so made a few mistakes with the pointer initialization in main and integer character constant. Thanks alot.

Comment: Minor correction to the last line: the second code works because the address *of an array* is equal to the address *of its first element* (close enough).  Although the analogous statement about structures and their first members is true too, it does not factor in here.